# How to specify a unsafe/safe write with pymongo's collection.update_one or update_many

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the connection defaulted to w=0
but for collection.update_one or collection.update_many, I want to set the write_concern per operation by setting the parameter w=0. Instead I'm getting this error:

```
update_one() got an unexpected keyword argument 'w'
```

What is the right way to do this? I saw that insert accepts 'w' but not update_one or update_many. Why?

Comment: I also faced the same problem and added code in their github repo, here is the pull request if you want to explicitly specify write_concern in update_one or update_many operation https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/pull/313

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new way to override a PyMongo client's, database's, or collection's write concern is using "with_options":

```
client = MongoClient(w=0)
collection = client.database.collection
w1_collection = collection.with_options(write_concern=WriteConcern(w=1))
w1_collection.update_one({'_id': 1}, {'$inc': {'x': 3}})
```

See the docs for [write concern](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/write_concern.html) and [with_options](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.with_options)

Comment: This gives NameError: name 'WriteConcern' is not defined

Comment: @PranoyGn were you able to figure this out?